# Preserve directory tree while copying files with cp

Tags: bash, shell, terminal, cp

I have about 1000 folders that I want to extract a single file from to upload to a server but I need to preserve the directory tree.

```
cp */myFile.txt ../newTree
```

Is what I basically want to do but instead of each file being saved to `../newTree/myFile.txt` I want it to be `../newTree/*/myFile.txt` where the `*` is the wildcard from the `cp` command.

I couldn't find a flag in the man file for this so I'm thinking I may need another utility besides `cp`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

With rsync:

```
find ./ -name myFile.txt -print0|rsync -0adv --files-from=- ./ ../newTree/
```

Without rsync:

You can find all files, for each file you create the directory in the newTree, and copy the file to it.

```
for file in */myFile.txt; do
    dir=$(dirname "$file")
    mkdir -p "../newTree/$dir"
    cp "$file" "../newTree/$dir"
done
```

Comment: Thanks, I don't really understand the rsync but I will look into it. The script is more in line with my comfort level

Comment: Just a followup to this, it should be `dir=$(dirname "$file")`

Answer (score 5):

Store all the files in a `tar` archive , then extract it on the server.

Comment: or do the same, sending the output from tar to stdout, then piping to another tar process that will unpack stdin: `find ./ -name myFile.txt -print0 | tar cvf - | tar xvf - -C ../newTree/`